# Unable to install Anydesk 5.5.1 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, remote-desktop

I am trying to break free from the shackles of Windows and am using Ubuntu for the first time. I am having a tough time installing Anydesk 5.5.1 in Ubuntu 18.04. I have read some of the posts which other users have posted. I have tried the following suggestions, but have not succeeded so far. Being Linux, I know that it can be done. The only thing is that since I am a novice, I am not having the requisite knowledge. I will be grateful to the experts in this community if they can help me install this software.

1. Anydesk installation Through GUI:

   - Went to https://anydesk.com/platforms
   - Downloaded - `anydesk_5.5.1-1_amd64.deb`
   - Right click - Clicked on **Open with Software**
   - Clicked on **Install** button
   - Authentication Required - Put the password
   - Installing 100% - Green progress bar moves from 0 to 100%
   - When I see in the Ubuntu software centre, this software is not installed.
2. Installation through terminal

   - Went to the downloads folder
   - `sudo apt install ./anydesk_5.5.1-1_amd64.deb`
   - Encountered the following error:

     ```
     Error -> The following packages have unmet dependencies.
      anydesk : Depends: libpango1.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
     E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
     ```

     Adding the output of sudo apt show libpango*

   Package: libpango-1.0-0
   Version: 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1
   Status: install ok installed
   Priority: optional
   Section: libs
   Source: pango1.0
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers 
   Installed-Size: 414 kB
   Depends: fontconfig (>= 2.1.91), libc6 (>= 2.14), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3), libthai0 (>= 0.1.22-3~)
   Homepage: http://www.pango.org/
   Download-Size: unknown
   APT-Manual-Installed: no
   APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
   Description: Layout and rendering of internationalised text
    Pango is a library for layout and rendering of text, with an emphasis on
    internationalization. Pango can be used anywhere that text layout is
    needed. however, most of the work on Pango-1.0 was done using the GTK+
    widget toolkit as a test platform. Pango forms the core of text and font
    handling for GTK+-2.0.
    .
    Pango is designed to be modular; the core Pango layout can be used with four different font backends:

   - Core X windowing system fonts
   - Client-side fonts on X using the Xft library
   - Direct rendering of scalable fonts using the FreeType library
   - Native fonts on Microsoft backends
     .
     This package contains the shared libraries.

   Package: libpango1.0-doc
   Version: 1.40.14-1
   Priority: optional
   Section: doc
   Source: pango1.0
   Origin: Ubuntu
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers 
   Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
   Installed-Size: 2,350 kB
   Recommends: libglib2.0-doc
   Homepage: http://www.pango.org/
   Supported: 5y
   Download-Size: 183 kB
   APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
   Description: Documentation files for the Pango
    Pango is a library for layout and rendering of text, with an emphasis
    on internationalization. Pango can be used anywhere that text layout is
    needed. however, most of the work on Pango-1.0 was done using the GTK+
    widget toolkit as a test platform. Pango forms the core of text and
    font handling for GTK+-2.0.
    .
    Pango is designed to be modular; the core Pango layout can be used with
    four different font backends:

   - Core X windowing system fonts
   - Client-side fonts on X using the Xft library
   - Direct rendering of scalable fonts using the FreeType library
   - Native fonts on Microsoft backends
     .
     This package contains the HTML documentation for the Pango in
     /usr/share/doc/libpango1.0-doc/ .

   Package: libpangocairo-1.0-0
   Version: 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1
   Status: install ok installed
   Priority: optional
   Section: libs
   Source: pango1.0
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers 
   Installed-Size: 92.2 kB
   Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libcairo2 (>= 1.12.10), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.37.5), libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.28.1)
   Homepage: http://www.pango.org/
   Download-Size: unknown
   APT-Manual-Installed: no
   APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
   Description: Layout and rendering of internationalised text
    Pango is a library for layout and rendering of text, with an emphasis on
    internationalization. Pango can be used anywhere that text layout is
    needed. however, most of the work on Pango-1.0 was done using the GTK+
    widget toolkit as a test platform. Pango forms the core of text and font
    handling for GTK+-2.0.
    .
    Pango is designed to be modular; the core Pango layout can be used with four different font backends:

   - Core X windowing system fonts
   - Client-side fonts on X using the Xft library
   - Direct rendering of scalable fonts using the FreeType library
   - Native fonts on Microsoft backends
     .
     This package contains the shared libraries.

   Package: libpangoft2-1.0-0
   Version: 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1
   Status: install ok installed
   Priority: optional
   Section: libs
   Source: pango1.0
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers 
   Installed-Size: 131 kB
   Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12), libfreetype6 (>= 2.3.5), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3), libharfbuzz0b (>= 1.2.6), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.37.2)
   Homepage: http://www.pango.org/
   Download-Size: unknown
   APT-Manual-Installed: no
   APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
   Description: Layout and rendering of internationalised text
    Pango is a library for layout and rendering of text, with an emphasis on
    internationalization. Pango can be used anywhere that text layout is
    needed. however, most of the work on Pango-1.0 was done using the GTK+
    widget toolkit as a test platform. Pango forms the core of text and font
    handling for GTK+-2.0.
    .
    Pango is designed to be modular; the core Pango layout can be used with four different font backends:

   - Core X windowing system fonts
   - Client-side fonts on X using the Xft library
   - Direct rendering of scalable fonts using the FreeType library
   - Native fonts on Microsoft backends
     .
     This package contains the shared libraries.

   Package: libpangoxft-1.0-0
   Version: 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1
   Status: install ok installed
   Priority: optional
   Section: libs
   Source: pango1.0
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers 
   Installed-Size: 74.8 kB
   Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0), libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libx11-6, libxft2 (>> 2.1.1), libxrender1
   Homepage: http://www.pango.org/
   Download-Size: unknown
   APT-Manual-Installed: no
   APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
   Description: Layout and rendering of internationalised text
    Pango is a library for layout and rendering of text, with an emphasis on
    internationalization. Pango can be used anywhere that text layout is
    needed. however, most of the work on Pango-1.0 was done using the GTK+
    widget toolkit as a test platform. Pango forms the core of text and font
    handling for GTK+-2.0.
    .
    Pango is designed to be modular; the core Pango layout can be used with four different font backends:

   - Core X windowing system fonts
   - Client-side fonts on X using the Xft library
   - Direct rendering of scalable fonts using the FreeType library
   - Native fonts on Microsoft backends
     .
     This package contains the shared libraries.

   Package: libpangomm-1.4-1v5
   Version: 2.40.1-4
   Priority: optional
   Section: libs
   Source: pangomm
   Origin: Ubuntu
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers 
   Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
   Installed-Size: 207 kB
   Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libcairomm-1.0-1v5 (>= 1.12.0), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0), libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.54.0), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.38.0), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.38.0), libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.2.0), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2)
   Conflicts: libpangomm-1.4-1
   Replaces: libpangomm-1.4-1
   Homepage: http://gtkmm.org
   Task: ubuntu-live, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-live-share, lubuntu-gtk-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-live, lubuntu-live-qt, lubuntu-live-gtk, ubuntustudio-desktop-core, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-desktop
   Supported: 5y
   Download-Size: 42.5 kB
   APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
   Description: C++ Wrapper for pango (shared libraries)
    Pangomm is a C++ wrapper for the pango library. Originally part of gtkmm,
    pangomm provides convenient C++ interfaces for handling both the layout
    and internationalization of text in graphical applications.
    .
    This package contains the shared library.

   Package: libpango1.0-dev
   Version: 1.40.14-1
   Priority: optional
   Section: libdevel
   Source: pango1.0
   Origin: Ubuntu
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers 
   Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
   Installed-Size: 1,921 kB
   Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 (= 1.40.14-1), libcairo2-dev (>= 1.12.10), libfontconfig1-dev (>= 2.10.91), libfreetype6-dev, libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.34.0), libharfbuzz-dev (>= 0.9.9), libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.40.14-1), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (= 1.40.14-1), libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.40.14-1), libpangoxft-1.0-0 (= 1.40.14-1), libx11-dev, libxft-dev, libxrender-dev, pkg-config, libc6 (>= 2.7), libcairo2 (>= 1.12.10), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.34.0), libx11-6, libxft2 (>> 2.1.1)
   Recommends: debhelper
   Suggests: imagemagick, libpango1.0-doc
   Homepage: http://www.pango.org/
   Supported: 5y
   Download-Size: 288 kB
   APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
   Description: Development files for the Pango
    Pango is a library for layout and rendering of text, with an emphasis
    on internationalization. Pango can be used anywhere that text layout is
    needed. however, most of the work on Pango-1.0 was done using the GTK+
    widget toolkit as a test platform. Pango forms the core of text and
    font handling for GTK+-2.0.
    .
    Pango is designed to be modular; the core Pango layout can be used with
    four different font backends:

   - Core X windowing system fonts
   - Client-side fonts on X using the Xft library
   - Direct rendering of scalable fonts using the FreeType library
   - Native fonts on Microsoft backends
     .
     This package contains the header files and some files needed for development
     with Pango.

   Package: libpangomm-1.4-dev
   Version: 2.40.1-4
   Priority: optional
   Section: libdevel
   Source: pangomm
   Origin: Ubuntu
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers 
   Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
   Installed-Size: 351 kB
   Depends: libpangomm-1.4-1v5 (= 2.40.1-4), libcairomm-1.0-dev (>= 1.12.0), libglibmm-2.4-dev (>= 2.48.0), libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.38.0)
   Homepage: http://gtkmm.org
   Supported: 5y
   Download-Size: 49.1 kB
   APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
   Description: C++ Wrapper for pango (development files)
    Pangomm is a C++ wrapper for the pango library. Originally part of gtkmm,
    pangomm provides convenient C++ interfaces for handling both the layout
    and internationalization of text in graphical applications.
    .
    This package contains the development files.

   Package: libpangomm-1.4-doc
   Version: 2.40.1-4
   Priority: optional
   Section: doc
   Source: pangomm
   Origin: Ubuntu
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers 
   Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
   Installed-Size: 5,223 kB
   Depends: lynx | www-browser, doc-base
   Suggests: gtkmm-documentation
   Homepage: http://gtkmm.org
   Supported: 5y
   Download-Size: 432 kB
   APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
   Description: C++ Wrapper for pango (documentation)
    Pangomm is a C++ wrapper for the pango library. Originally part of gtkmm,
    pangomm provides convenient C++ interfaces for handling both the layout
    and internationalization of text in graphical applications.
    .
    This package contains the documentation.

   Package: libpango3.0-cil
   Version: 2.99.3-2
   Priority: optional
   Section: universe/cli-mono
   Source: gtk-sharp3
   Origin: Ubuntu
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian CLI Libraries Team 
   Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
   Installed-Size: 185 kB
   Depends: cli-common (>= 0.5.1), libcairo1.10-cil (>= 2.99.3), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.43.1), libglib3.0-cil (>= 2.99.3), libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 3.2.8), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.36.8), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.36.8), libc6 (>= 2.2.5)
   Suggests: monodoc-gtk3.0-manual
   Homepage: http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp
   Download-Size: 38.9 kB
   APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
   Description: CLI binding for Pango
    This package provides the pango-sharp assembly that allows CLI (.NET)
    programs to use the Pango library.
    .
    GTK# 3.0 is a CLI (.NET) language binding for the GTK+ 3.0 toolkit and
    related libraries.

   Package: libpango1.0-0
   Version: 1.40.14-1
   Priority: optional
   Section: universe/libs
   Source: pango1.0
   Origin: Ubuntu
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers 
   Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
   Installed-Size: 33.8 kB
   Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.40.14-1), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (= 1.40.14-1), libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.40.14-1), libpangox-1.0-0 (>= 0.0.2-2~), libpangoxft-1.0-0 (= 1.40.14-1)
   Homepage: http://www.pango.org/
   Download-Size: 3,332 B
   APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
   Description: Layout and rendering of internationalized text (transitional package)
    Pango is a library for layout and rendering of text, with an emphasis on
    internationalization. Pango can be used anywhere that text layout is
    needed. however, most of the work on Pango-1.0 was done using the GTK+
    widget toolkit as a test platform. Pango forms the core of text and font
    handling for GTK+-2.0.
    .
    Pango is designed to be modular; the core Pango layout can be used with four different font backends:

   - Core X windowing system fonts
   - Client-side fonts on X using the Xft library
   - Direct rendering of scalable fonts using the FreeType library
   - Native fonts on Microsoft backends
     .
     This is a transitional package.

   Package: libpango-perl
   Version: 1.227-2build1
   Priority: optional
   Section: universe/perl
   Origin: Ubuntu
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian Perl Group 
   Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
   Installed-Size: 499 kB
   Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.16.0), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0), perl (>= 5.26.0-4), perlapi-5.26.0, libcairo-perl, libglib-perl
   Homepage: http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/
   Task: lubuntu-gtk-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop
   Supported: 3y
   Download-Size: 157 kB
   APT-Manual-Installed: no
   APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
   Description: Perl module to layout and render international text
    Pango is a library for laying out and rendering text, with an emphasis on
    internationalization. Pango can be used anywhere that text layout is needed,
    but using Pango in conjunction with Cairo and/or Gtk2 provides a complete
    solution with high quality text handling and graphics rendering.
    .
    This package provides the Perl bindings for the Pango library.

   Package: libpangox-1.0-0
   Version: 0.0.2-5
   Priority: extra
   Section: universe/oldlibs
   Source: pangox-compat
   Origin: Ubuntu
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers 
   Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
   Installed-Size: 169 kB
   Pre-Depends: multiarch-support
   Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.34.0), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.32.5-3~), libx11-6
   Breaks: libpango1.0-0 (<< 1.32.5-2)
   Replaces: libpango1.0-0 (<< 1.32.5-2)
   Task: ubuntustudio-publishing, ubuntustudio-photography, ubuntustudio-graphics
   Download-Size: 41.7 kB
   APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
   Description: pango library X backend
    Pango is a library for layout and rendering of text, with an emphasis on
    internationalization. Pango can be used anywhere that text layout is
    needed. however, most of the work on Pango-1.0 was done using the GTK+
    widget toolkit as a test platform. Pango forms the core of text and font
    handling for GTK+-2.0.
    .
    Pango is designed to be modular; the core Pango layout can be used with four different font backends:

   - Core X windowing system fonts
   - Client-side fonts on X using the Xft library
   - Direct rendering of scalable fonts using the FreeType library
   - Native fonts on Microsoft backends
     .
     This package contains the Core X backend.

   Package: libpangox-1.0-dev
   Version: 0.0.2-5
   Priority: extra
   Section: universe/libdevel
   Source: pangox-compat
   Origin: Ubuntu
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers 
   Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
   Installed-Size: 209 kB
   Depends: libpangox-1.0-0 (= 0.0.2-5), libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.34.0), libpango1.0-dev, libx11-dev, libxrender-dev, pkg-config
   Breaks: libpango1.0-dev (<< 1.32.5-2)
   Replaces: libpango1.0-dev (<< 1.32.5-2)
   Download-Size: 41.7 kB
   APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
   Description: pango library X backend - development files
    Pango is a library for layout and rendering of text, with an emphasis on
    internationalization. Pango can be used anywhere that text layout is
    needed. however, most of the work on Pango-1.0 was done using the GTK+
    widget toolkit as a test platform. Pango forms the core of text and font
    handling for GTK+-2.0.
    .
    Pango is designed to be modular; the core Pango layout can be used with four different font backends:

   - Core X windowing system fonts
   - Client-side fonts on X using the Xft library
   - Direct rendering of scalable fonts using the FreeType library
   - Native fonts on Microsoft backends
     .
     This package contains the development files for the Core X backend.

   Package: libpangomm-1.4-1
   State: not a real package (virtual)
   N: There are 4 additional records. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.

Comment: Have you ran 'apt update' and 'apt upgrade' ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and help. I shall run both these commands and post the results.

Comment: I  ran apt update and got the following result: Fetched 4,635 kB in 23s (199 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.

Comment: When  I ran apt upgrade, I got the following result: 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

Comment: After running the above two commands, I again tried Anydesk installation Through GUI and Installation through terminal (Same steps listed above), but I am getting the same errors listed above. Summary: Both these commands did not help me install Anydesk. Kindly help

Comment: Can you please include in your question the input of the following command:  sudo apt show libpango*

Comment: Please remove all those comments and add the output to your question! (Editing it)

Comment: I have deleted all the comments containing the output and added the output to the question.

Comment: Only install this pakage: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libpango-1.0-0/download Then install .deb file

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and solved by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

It seems that "libpango1.0-0" and "libgtkglext1" have not been installed, so there were errors with anydesk.
After the apt-get upgrade, the system recommended me to fix these error.

Answer (score 2):

if you have downloaded the deb file than go to the directory where it is located and open the terminal and try this :

`sudo dpkg -i anydesk_5.5.1-1_amd64.deb`

if you still faces issues with dependencies execute the following command to install the required dependencies.

`sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and help. I am not having that particular linux machine with me right now. I shall run both these commands and post the results.

Comment: When I try this sudo dpkg -i anydesk_5.5.1-1_amd64.deb I get this error message: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of anydesk:
 anydesk depends on libpango1.0-0; however:
  Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.
 anydesk depends on libgtkglext1; however:
  Package libgtkglext1 is not installed.
continued in next post...

Comment: dpkg: error processing package anydesk (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 anydesk

Comment: When I try this: sudo apt-get install -f I get this message:Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  anydesk
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 12.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 134614 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing anydesk (5.5.1) ...
continued in next comment...

Comment: Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...

Comment: Summary: Both these commands did not help me install Anydesk. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, directly installing some deb file should be your last choice when installing software on ubuntu. Better use their repository as suggested [here](http://deb.anydesk.com/howto.html?_ga=2.40850210.1472739393.1586445539-2104800080.1584956681):

obtain root priviledges

```
sudo su
```

add repository key to Trusted software providers list

```
wget -qO - https://keys.anydesk.com/repos/DEB-GPG-KEY | apt-key add -
```

add the repository:

```
echo "deb http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk-stable.list
```

update apt cache:

```
apt update
```

install anydesk:

```
apt install anydesk
```

Comment: For anyone getting stuck on "The following packages have unmet dependencies: anydesk: Depends: libgtkglext1 but it is not installable", you might need to `add-apt-repository universe` before `apt install anydesk`. I bumped into this when running Ubuntu from a live USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

then just resuming my Anydesk installation process

```
 wget -qO - https://keys.anydesk.com/repos/DEB-GPG-KEY | apt-key add -
    echo "deb http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk-stable.list 
    apt update 
    sudo apt install anydesk
```